# Grails GraphQL plugin - controller not running when deployed to Heroku

Tags: heroku, grails, graphql, grails-orm

I have a simple Grails-React app using the React profile that works fine locally but has an issue with the GraphQL plugin not being loaded when deploying to Heroku, it uses:

- Grails 3.3.10
- JDK 8
- Gradle 4.4 (locally)  remote on Heroku? I don't know.
- Grails React profile
- GraphQL plugin 1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

The code is here: https://github.com/wellsst/grails3-react-diceware

Running locally with `server:bootRun` and `heroku local -f ProcfileLocal` the log entry appears:
`INFO --- [           main] g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager     : Grails plug-in [gormGraphql] with version [1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT] loaded successfully`

But remotely on Heroku no errors are shown nor is any logging for GraphQL.

Hitting the "application" controller I see nothing GraphQL and only 1 controller:

```
{"message":"Welcome to Grails!","environment":"production","appversion":"1","grailsversion":"3.3.10","appprofile":"react","groovyversion":"2.4.17","jvmversion":"1.8.0_222-heroku","reloadingagentenabled":false,"artefacts":{"controllers":1,"domains":1,"services":0},"controllers":[{"name":"grails3.react.diceware.ApplicationController","logicalPropertyName":"application"}],"plugins":[{"name":"i18n","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"dataBinding","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"restResponder","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"jsonView","version":"1.2.9"},{"name":"eventBus","version":"3.3.2"},{"name":"core","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"dataSource","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"codecs","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"controllers","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"urlMappings","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"mimeTypes","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"domainClass","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"converters","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"controllersAsync","version":"3.3.2"},{"name":"hibernate","version":"6.1.12"},{"name":"services","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"interceptors","version":"3.3.10"},{"name":"cache","version":"4.0.1"}]}
```

I am suspecting it is the version of gradle on Heroku or something about how the GraphQL plugin is configured.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My fudge around for this was to deploy to Cloud Foundry, no issues.  I suspect it around the different versions of gradle (locally vs remote)